# Error when trying to create a self-signed certificate for my mail server

Tags: linux, email, debian, ssl, dovecot

I am configuring my mail server and when I try to create a self-signed SSL certificate something happens.

[image: Error given by the mkcert.sh dovecot script]

When I first executed the script, an error ocurred which was that the /etc/dovecot/ssl was not created and I just created the directory using mkdir. Then when I executed the script again, the given error appeared.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Be sure that the new directory has the correct permision. chmod /etc/dovecot/ssl 777 or whatever might be.

Comment: Why not simply use a LetsEncrypt certificate?

Comment: Because this is homework and I cannot do it another way.